# Windows version from a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to add to a script that gets the windows version, Ex. `21H2`.

I can get the OS name and build, but really need the `21H2`.

What I have is:

```
systeminfo | findstr /B /C:"OS Name" /C:"OS Version"
```

And I get:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
OS Version:                10.0.19044 N/A Build 19044
```

Does anyone know how to get the `21H2`, without using `PowerShell`, *(which is disallowed in my work environment)*.

Comment: …just a quick guess: `wmic OS get Caption,Name,Version`?

Comment: Version 21H2 is build 19044, version 21H1 is build 19043, version 20H2 is build 19042, version 2004 is build 19041. Why do you need the version name rather than the build number? Also `systeminfo` is the possibly the slowest command you can run on Windows, and WMIC, is soon to be removed from Windows 11 so any script using it will very quickly be of no use moving forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of my earlier comment, the simplest, and quickest way to retrieve the result requested in your specific question is:

```bash
@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /V DisplayVersion 2^>NUL') Do @Echo %%H
```

[EDIT /]

BTW, based upon my earlier comment, you can change `DisplayVersion` to `CurrentBuildNumber`, if `19044` will still satisfy your requirements. This could be useful because the number can be better used in comparisons with `IF` and `EQU`/`GTR`/`GEQ`/`LSS`/`LEQ` etc.

---

And if you want the OS, Edition, Version, and Build all in one command, you could probably expand that to something like this:

```bash
@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=1,2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /T REG_SZ 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RIC:"^  *CurrentBuildN" /C:"  *ProductN" /C:"  *D" ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe /R') Do @Set /P "=%%I " 0<NUL
```

Alternatively modify the output:

```bash
@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=1,2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /T REG_SZ 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RIC:"^  *CurrentBuildN" /C:"  *ProductN" /C:"  *D"') Do @Echo %%G: %%I "
```

Or define three variables:

```bash
@For /F "EOL=H Tokens=1,2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /T REG_SZ 2^>NUL ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /RIC:"^  *CurrentBuildN" /C:"  *ProductN" /C:"  *D"') Do @Set "%%G=%%I"
```