# Modify powershell output

Tags: powershell, batch-file, output

I have the following script that the great community on this site helped me create.
I run this as part of a batch script

```
powershell -Command Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' 'DisplayVersion' >> C:\ProgramData\Data_Mover\info.txt
```

It will write the os build to the txt file (EX: `21H2`)

What I need is to add this before the `21H2`:

```
Build :
```

I have looked online and similar scripts with no luck

Does anyone know how to get the requested output?

Comment: What do you want to add before it? Can you clarify more on that?

Comment: What's wrong with modifying [the code I already gave you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73228334), and you accepted a week ago? ```@(For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2,*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe Query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /V DisplayVersion 2^>NUL') Do @Echo Build : %%H) 1>>"C:\ProgramData\Data_Mover\info.txt"```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell offers several ways to prepend `Build :`  to the output from your `Get-ItemPropertyValue` call: string concatenation with `+`, string interpolation via a [double-quoted string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) (`"..."`), or use of the [`-f` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f).

Here, `+` is the simplest choice, as it doesn't introduce additional escaping considerations when you pass the command from `cmd.exe` (a batch file) via `powershell.exe`, the Windows PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe):

```bash
powershell.exe -Command "'Build : ' + (Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion' DisplayVersion)"
```

Note that, for robustness, I've enclosed the entire command in `"..."`; for brevity, I've omitted the `>>` redirection.